# indexedDB query inside of cursor loop

Tags: javascript, html, cursor, indexeddb

I have an indexeddb database, and in it i am running a cursor. Inside of the cursor callback function, I need to run some more queries. Do I do this by creating a whole new connection with `indexedDB.open()`, should i just call `transaction.get()` and it will work, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use existing transaction. The is the point of transaction in the first place. You can also create another transaction as well. BTW, no `get` method in transaction.

Comment: yeah i guess it is obectstore.get. But I can use those methods even if i am already within a cursor callback?

Comment: definitely, so that all requests in single transaction.